# Git: unable to pull/see my teammates changes on my local branch

Tags: git

I Have a branch local and on remote.My teammate made a few changes to it and pushed them on remote branch. I tried doing a git pull origin branch-name but cannot see the changes he made.Has anyone faced this issue before?It just did a automatic merge and now shows all files up-to-date

Comment: If he was in a different branch, you need to be on the same branch to see his changes.

Comment: Check if the origin is the remote branch where your team mate has pushed.

Comment: yes it is on the same remote branch that I had pushed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there aren't any conflicting changes (meaning all changes are in different lines) git will merge automaticaly and merge the changes made ny both of you. I recomend using [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) to see all the differences with an older commit and see if you can spot any change you haven't made.